# Fire $emit event if model property change

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass some data from child controller to parent controller using `$emit` + `$on` .

Here is my code.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
        $scope.message = 'parent';

        $scope.$on('EventFromChild', function (event, data) { 
          console.log("Event Received");
          $scope.message = data;
        });        
    }])
    .controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.data ={"name":"Amit","lastname":"kumar"};
        $scope.$emit('EventFromChild',$scope.data.name);
        $scope.update = function(){
          console.log("Clicked");
          $scope.data.name ="Testing";
        };
    }]);
```

When page is loaded then, Then it successfully passes the data from the child to parent, **But when I update the data in child then I also want it to get reflected in parent controller**, But it is not emitting the event.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P2hY47fn7f9KyRt4EAn4?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are doing nothing when the child is updated.

You have to use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for observing changes. For example, if you want emit changes when `data.name` changes:

```
    $scope.$watch('data.name', function() {
      $scope.$emit('EventFromChild',$scope.data.name);
    });
```

Or when any property of `data` changes:

```
    $scope.$watch('data', function() {
      $scope.$emit('EventFromChild',$scope.data);
    });
```

This way the come becomes:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
  .controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
      $scope.message = 'parent';

      $scope.$on('EventFromChild', function (event, data) { 
        console.log("Event Received");
        $scope.message = data;
      });        
  }])
  .controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.data ={"name":"Amit","lastname":"kumar"};
      $scope.$emit('EventFromChild',$scope.data.name);
      $scope.update = function(){
        console.log("Clicked");
        $scope.data.name ="Testing";
      };
      $scope.$watch('data.name', function() {
        $scope.$emit('EventFromChild', $scope.data.name);
      });
  }]);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
// Code goes here
mc = angular.module('app', [
  'app.controllers',
]);

angular.module('app.controllers', [])
    .controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
        $scope.message = 'parent';
       
        $scope.$on('EventFromChild', function (event, data) { 
          console.log("Event Received");
          $scope.message = data;
        });        
    }])
    .controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.data ={"name":"Amit","lastname":"kumar"};
        $scope.update = function(){
          console.log("Clicked");
          $scope.data.name ="Testing";
        };
        $scope.$watch('data.name', function() {
          $scope.$emit('EventFromChild',$scope.data.name);
        });
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="parentCtrl">
       <b>Parent Event:</b> {{message}}<br />
       <br/><br/>
      <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
        <b>Child Event:</b> {{data.name}}<br />
          <input type="button" ng-click="update()" value ="update"/>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```